# How to use google play services plugins on phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-games

I am developing an android game using phonegap build.I wanted to use the google play leaderboards and found this link.
https://github.com/ptgamr/cordova-google-play-game

I understood the working of the plugin but the documentation specifies a command line installation of the plugin which is not possible as i am building the app on phonegap build.

I was looking for something like `<gap:plugin name="" version="" />` but found nothing.
Any help how to proceed regarding this issue would be great.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for this

```
//caution: replace 1064334934918 with your google play game app id
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-game" source="npm" >
<param name="APP_ID" value="1064334934918" />
</gap:plugin>
```

for full api visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-game